# Abbreviate a string using dictionary in C

Tags: c, strings

> Looking for Code Review:
>     Abbreviate a given string using a dictionary of acceptable
>   abbreviations.
>
> Notes:
>
> Only "whole words" should be abbreviated. That is, if the word
>   "record" can be abbreviated to "rec", "records" SHOULD NOT be
>   abbreviated to "recs".
>
> - A "whole word" is a sequence of alphanumeric characters.
> - If the abbreviated string will not fit in the destination buffer clamp the string.
> - Bonus points for allowing the substitution to be case insensitive, but also case aware. It should handle three cases, the original word
>     all lower case, all upper case, or the first letter only being
>     capitalized. Mixed cases can be handled in any reasonable way.
> - For example, if the dictionary contains: "record"->"rec":
>
>   - "record" should be replaced with "rec"
>   - "Record" should be replaced with "Rec"
>   - "RECORD" should be replaced with "REC"
>   - "ReCord" can be replaced with "rec", "Rec" or "REC"
> - `@param str` - source string to abbreviate (NULL terminated)
> - `@param str_abbr` - destination buffer to store abbreviated version of 'str'
> - `@param str_abbr_len` - length of 'str_abbr' buffer, including NULL terminator
> - `@param dictionary` - array of acceptable abbreviations
> - `@param dictionary_len` - number of items in dictionary

**abbr.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    const char * full;
    const char * abbr;
} dictionary_t;

void abbreviate_string(const char * str, char * str_abbr, size_t str_abbr_len, dictionary_t * dictionary, size_t dictionary_len);

const char* CheckMatchinDictionary(char *result, dictionary_t* dictionary, size_t dictionary_len );
```

**abbr.c**

```
#include "abbr.h"

void abbreviate_string(const char * str, char * str_abbr, size_t str_abbr_len, dictionary_t * dictionary, size_t dictionary_len)
{
    const char* inputString = str;
    char ** wordArray  = NULL;
    int numOfWords = 0;

    char* word = strtok (inputString," ,-.:;");
    while (word != NULL)
    {
        wordArray = realloc (wordArray, sizeof (char*) * ++numOfWords);

        //Check memory allocation
        if(wordArray == NULL)
            exit(-1);

        wordArray[numOfWords - 1] = word;
        word = strtok (NULL, " ,-.:;");
    }

    memset(str_abbr, 0, str_abbr_len - 1);
    int i;
    int stringLength = 0;
    for(i=0; i < numOfWords; ++i )
    {
        const char* result = CheckMatchinDictionary(wordArray[i], dictionary, dictionary_len );

        // Append to the str_abbr only if fits in the destination buffer
        if( stringLength < str_abbr_len - 1)
        {
            if(result != NULL)
            {
                strcat(str_abbr, result);
                stringLength += strlen(result);
            }
            else
            {
                strcat(str_abbr, wordArray[i]);
                stringLength += strlen(wordArray[i]);
            }

            strcat(str_abbr, " ");
            stringLength += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(result != NULL)
                strncat(str_abbr, result, str_abbr_len - stringLength - 1);
            else
                strncat(str_abbr, wordArray[i], str_abbr_len - stringLength - 1 );
        }

    }
    //printf("The abbreviated string is %s\n", str_abbr);

}

// Function to check the match from the dictionary
const char* CheckMatchinDictionary(char *input, dictionary_t* dictionary, size_t dictionary_len )
{
    unsigned int index;
    for(index=0; index < dictionary_len; ++index)
    {
        if(strcmp(dictionary[index].full, input) == 0)
            return dictionary[index].abbr;

        else if(strcasecmp(dictionary[index].full, input) == 0)
        {
           size_t length = strlen(dictionary[index].abbr);
           char* substr = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
           strncpy(substr, input, length);
           substr[length + 1] = '\0';
           return substr;
        }

    }

    return NULL;
}
```

**main**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abbr.h"

int main(void)
{
    /* Sample Dictionary */
    dictionary_t dictionary[] =
    {
        {"record", "rec"},
        {"maximum", "max"},
        {"minimum", "min"},
        {"number", "no"}
    };

    char str[100];
    char str_abbr[100];

    strcpy(str, "maximum record rate is:");

    abbreviate_string(str, str_abbr, sizeof(str_abbr), dictionary,   sizeof(dictionary) / sizeof(dictionary[0]));

    printf("%s -> %s\n", str, str_abbr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted `abbr.h` from the review.

Comment: Changing the post once answers come in is not good site etiquette.  I recommend that you rollback the code edit.  If anything,  appending _critical_ missing code/corrections may  be a good alternative.

Comment: I added the abbr.h just as you all suggested. I am new to this page. All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @kavi687 The edit not only added code, it subtracted code from the `main.c` part.  Suggest reviewing  [After you ask your question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2439/29485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Save time.  **Compile code with all warnings enabled**.
2. Format code, with an auto formatter (saves time).  Even better, unless a width is specified,  Format narrow enough to prevent horizontal scroll bars when posted here.
3. Members of `dictionary_t` used in code before definition.  If `dictionary_t` was defined in `"abbr.h"`, then its re-declaration does not belong in `main.c`
4. `#include <string.h>` missing before call of `strtok()`.  Standard include files should not be counted on to exist in `"abbr.h"`.
5. Calling `strtok (inputString,...` with `const char* inputString` is *undefined behavior* as `inputString` points to `const` data.
6. `#include <stdlib.h>` missing before call of `realloc()`.
7. Rather than `sizeof (char*)`, use `sizeof *wordArray` in `wordArray = realloc (wordArray, sizeof (char*) * ++numOfWords);`.  It is easier to code correctly, review and maintain.
8. `CheckMatchinDictionary()` called before declaration.
9. `if( stringLength < str_abbr_len - 1)` mixes signed-ness of compare. Suggest

   ```
   size_t str_abbr_len

   // int stringLength = 0;
   //....
   // if( stringLength < str_abbr_len - 1)

   size_t stringLength = 0;
   ....
   if(stringLength + 1 < str_abbr_len)
   ```
10. Strange code uses `-1` in `memset(str_abbr, 0, str_abbr_len - 1);`  If `str_abbr_len == 0`, then a far-too-big value is passed to `memset()`.  Further, this does not completely fill the called array with zeros.  (Bug?) Recommend `memset(str_abbr, 0, str_abbr_len);`.  Further:  Suggest name change:  to `str_abbr_len` to `str_abbr_size`.  The *length* of a *string* does not count the *null character*.  *Size* better conveys the size of the array that holds a string.
11. `strcasecmp()` is not a standard C library function.  Easier enough to make an equivalent function with `tolower(), toupper()`.
12. Good attempted use of `const`.
13. The missing `"abbr.h"` unnecessarily complicated the review.  [@Toby Speight](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187923/#comment358934_187923)  Better to have added it.
14. Bug? I would have expected `stringLength` updated in the `else` block.
15. As the function does not change the dictionary, code could use `const` to better convey code's function and allow some optimizations.

    ```
    void abbreviate_string(const char * str, char * str_abbr, size_t str_abbr_len, 
        // dictionary_t * dictionary, size_t dictionary_len)
        const dictionary_t * dictionary, size_t dictionary_len)
    ```
16. Advanced: pointers certainly do not point to overlapped data, so add `restrict` for additional optimization potential.

    ```
    void abbreviate_string(const char * restrict str, char * restrict str_abbr, 
        size_t str_abbr_len, const dictionary_t * restrict dictionary, 
        size_t dictionary_len)
    ```
17. A common idiom is to place the pointers to changed data first, rather than in the middle.

    ```
    //abbreviate_string(str, str_abbr, str_abbr_len, dictionary, dictionary_len)
      abbreviate_string(str_abbr, str_abbr_len, str, dictionary, dictionary_len)
    ```
18. Appended  `abbr.h` should be tolerant of being included multiple times.  Research [*code guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: Debug tip: when printing constructed strings, add sentinels to the output like `[]` in `printf("%s -> [%s]\n", str, str_abbr);`  Easier to detect unexpected leading/trailing white-space.